# Number of words with a given number of letters.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be the set of the alphabet, $card(A)=26$. The set of all words with three letters has $26^3$ elements, this is just the cardinality of the cartesian product $A\times A\times A$. Now I want to write this as the set of functions from a set $E$ to a set $F$. I suggest that $F$ is the set $A$ of the alphabet and $E$ is the set of positions $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ and then $26^3$ is the set of functions that send every position $p_i$ to one of the letters of the alphabet. Is this correct? Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed!  Nicely done.${}$

Comment: Ok. Now suppose I don't know the answer $26^3$ why couldn't we think about the map that sends any letter to a position rather than sending a position to a letter?

Comment: Because then, for example, you'd have $p_1p_2p_3p_1p_2p_3...p_1p_2$ as a member of the set, where the positions (from left to right) are what $a$ through $z$ (respectively) are sent to. This is not a $3$-letter word in the alphabet $A,$ but rather a $26$-"letter" word in the alphabet $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}.$

Comment: The upshot is that there are $3$ positions, and we *must* choose a letter for each in order to get a word as desired. It is *not* the case that we must choose a position for every letter.